# SQLiteOpenHelper not calling onCreate

Tags: android, sqlite, oncreate, sqliteopenhelper

This is the fist time I've used SQLiteOpenHelper (or databases on android).  When I get a writeable database I was wondering why onCreate isnt being called on each new instance of the class.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private String PrSQLcmd = "";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Contact(Firstname TEXT, LastName TEXT");
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: Did you try uninstall application? May be you already have database, so it doesn't call `onCreate`.

Comment: You were completely correct, I was forgetting it simply looked at the database NOT the tables I was trying to add.  Worked perfectly.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov +1 because that is the most common error for all these related posts. So easy to forget about it when you come back to an old project.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In SQLiteOpenHelper, the meaning of 'onCreate' is different from what it is in an Activity. Here,'onCreate' is called only once, which is the first time you create the database. The next time you run the app, the database is already there, so it won't call 'onCreate'. Your object level initialization should be done in the constructor and not in 'onCreate'

To see 'onCreate' being called, either manually delete the db file, or simply uninstall the app.

Comment: Your database will get created when you call getWritableDatabase()/readableDatabase(), which open existing database or create new one if not exists. So, onCreate only get called once after that database will be cached and will be supplied according to the requests made for reading or writing.