# Android SQLite: Calling the onCreate Method and passing in an Object

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a database for an Android app I am working on.  I am trying to learn how to code following the correct standards and I read that in the onCreate method of the DbHelper class is where you database gets created.  I also read that it is in the onCreate method that you should populate your database with data.  Is this correct?  And if so how do I pass an object to the onCreate method so I can loop through it and populate the database?

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
private static String DATABASE_NAME = "FodoSubstitutes.db";
private static String FOOD_TABLE = "Food";

//Creates the database with db name and calls onCreate(). 
public DbHelper(Context context) 
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    //System.out.println("in onCreate");
    //assocID   food    healthierFood category  description count submittedBy
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + FOOD_TABLE +
                "(Food_ID integer primary key, " + 
                "Food_Name string not null, " +
                "Food_Aliases string, " + 
                "Hints string, " +
                "Category string, " + 
                "Subcategory string, " +
                "Description string, " + 
                "Submission_ID int, " +
                "Comment_ID int, " + 
                "Count int); ";
   db.execSQL(sql);

}
}
```

My thought was to do something like this.
`DbHelper.onCreate(Food myFoodObj);`

but that will not work.  Any thoughts?  It is has got to be something simple and obvious that I am overlooking.

Comment: Break this into two parts. Part one: Create the database. Part two: create a method that will update the database with your object, say create a method called 'addFood', where you execute an appropriate `db.execSQL`, `db.query` and so forth. You'll probably need some helper methods as well, for checking the database exists and so on. Also, keep this in mind: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7164505/429047

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not necessary to populate your database with data inside `onCreate()`. onCreate() is just used to create database and tables.

> My thought was to do something like this. DbHelper.onCreate(Food
>   myFoodObj);

This is wrong, you don't need to call onCreate(). `onCreate()` will get called itself when you just reference an instance of the class in which you are using the Database class.

```
DbHelper dbhelper = new DbHelper(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DBAdapter {

 String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + FOOD_TABLE +
                "(Food_ID integer primary key, " + 
                "Food_Name string not null, " +
                "Food_Aliases string, " + 
                "Hints string, " +
                "Category string, " + 
                "Subcategory string, " +
                "Description string, " + 
                "Submission_ID int, " +
                "Comment_ID int, " + 
                "Count int); ";
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter (Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(sql );

        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM" + DATABASE_USERSTATUS);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    // ---opens the database---
    public SecureSMSDBAdapterAES open() throws SQLException {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        return this;
    }

    // ---closes the database---
    public void close() {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    // ---insert values into the database---

    public long insertDataByQuery(String q) {

        db.execSQL(q);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

And in the class where u want to instantiate the database

DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
dbAdapter.open();
//If any queries write here
dbadapter.close();

And u can follow this tutorial

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0):

The onCreate method in SQLiteOpenHelper is for creating a database... and i think it is not useful to populate your database in onCreate method..
as user1203673 said..you can add this part of code to DBAdapter class to populate database..

```
public void createcustom(String category,String subcategory){
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
values.put(Category string,category);
values.put(Subcategory string,subcategory);
long insertId = customdb.insert(sqliteplaylist.LIBRARY, null,values);

}
```

and call this from your activity as "DBAdapter.createcustom(foodname,foodcategory);"

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing.  I created a DataLyaer Class that works witht he DbHelper that looks like this.

```
public class DataLayer 
{

private DbHelper _dbHelper;

public DataLayer(Context c) 
{
    _dbHelper = new DbHelper(c);
}


public void populateMyDB(Table myTables ) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = _dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    try 
    {
        //do stuff. 

    }
    finally
    {
        if (db != null)
            db.close();
    }

}
}
```

And then I call my DataLayer by doing this.

```
DataLayer d = new DataLayer(context);
d.populateMyDB(myFood);
```

Thanks for the help.  The problem was I couldn't figure out how to add this stuff in the onCreate() method or even in my DbHelper class.  I guess I can't believe anyone who posts something online.